# How to ensure atomic reads and atomic writes?

Tags: java, atomic

I want atomic reads and atomic writes to Integer (not int) and others as follows:

```
volatile Double a; // not double
volatile Long b; // not long
Integer c; // not int
Boolean d; // not boolean
```

If not, how would I make them atomic?

Edit: As a clarification, I do not need an atomic operation that combines read and write.  I just need the read to be atomic and the write to be atomic, separately.

Edit2: @Peter Lawrey, @PeterLawrey, This is ironic:
`Double a;
a = 0.5d;` Here the write is atomic because `a` is a reference.  While in this
`double a;
a = 0.5d;` the write is not be guaranteed to be atomic. And yet the `Double` wraps a `double`.  Of course I would not expect the same to apply to the wrapped contents of arbitrary objects that have references read and written atomicly.

Edit3: Additional note, I originally wanted to get atomic reads and writes thinking that atomicity ensures consistency across threads.  I found that it doesn't and that you still need volatility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All reads or writes to references are atomic.

I assume you mean you want to do a read and a write atomicly. In that case I would use AtomicReference, AtomicLong, AtomicInteger or AtomicBoolean as approriate . If performance is important to you I would use `int` `long` or `double` instead of wrappers.

For consistency between threads you need `volatile`. For atomic operations like increment and swap, you can use AtomicReference, AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater, AtomicLong, AtomicInteger, AtomicBoolean, AtomicIntegerArray, AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater and AtomicLongArray AtomicLongFieldUpdater classes.  To perform such atomic operations on a `double`, you can build your own updater with Unsafe, but use at your own risk. ;)

Comment: No I just meant an atomic read.  And an atomic write.  They don't need to be together.

Comment: All reference access are atomic.  The only access not guaranteed to be atomic is non-volatile access to `double` or `long`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have you mistaken shouldn't you use?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Instead?